# Will Visual Studio 2013 function normally on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, compatibility, visual-studio

I need Visual Studio 2013 for my computer science class and I'm wondering if the upgrade to Windows 10 will affect how it runs in any way.

Comment: You don't _need_ Visual Studio _2013_, but _yes_ it will work fine on Windows 10. Visual Studio 2015 (which is free now) would probably run better and you should probably just get that.

Comment: @Insane Only the VS 2015 Community edition is "free", but it imposes limits as to what you can produce with it: https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Guarantee on my life he won't need any of the paid features of 2015 for his computer science class. The differences are negligible imo :P

Comment: + Just realized you were talking about _what_ can be produced. I assume that won't matter to a CS student either (as I am one and it doesn't)

Comment: I'm not saying you wrong, I'm just pointing out that VS 2015 (in general) is not "free".

Comment: If the class says to use 2013, then use 2013.

Comment: @Keltari I know that's why I didn't want to download 2015!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used VS 2013 (Standard) on my Windows 7 machine, and upgrading to Windows 10 made no difference in how it behaved or acted.  It works just like it did before. But since I don't use every single part of VS, I'll issue a "Your Mileage May Vary" warning. :)

For more anecdotal evidence, perhaps check out this Reddit thread: [Has anyone used Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 10 TP?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/2i6wv8/has_anyone_used_visual_studio_2013_on_windows_10/), where practically everyone says "works for me".

As Insane mentioned in his comment, if you're worried about OS compatibility, then you should use a newer version of VS. But since this of a for learning in a class, check with your instructor before you do that, as there may be mild differences that may affect you following instructions meant for an older version.